# Banner Ads under UISplitViewController overlaid by MasterViewController's UITableView

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, iad

The picture shows exactly what the problem is. Ads are being overshadowed by the UITableView. I followed the SplitNavigationBanner project provided by apple and changed it so I can switch between navigation controllers and split view controllers within the app.

The setup is this - 1st VC that loads is a navigation view. Ads are hidden but loaded. I then switch over to the Split VC and have ads shown. The result is the picture below.

More Info - I printed all the sizes and everything matches up. In other words, the split view controller and master view controller within it are exactly the same height. Yet it's clear there is a shadow over the ads. If ads are loaded AFTER the split VC is shown to screen, there is no problem with ads. Everything lines up at that point. This issue does not occur if the master view controller is a tab view controller.

Any thoughts what would cause the shadow over the banner ads? Maybe it's the way the subviews are loaded?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes along, the solution was quite simple:

The sizes were all correct but how they were layered in the view mattered. In other words, the hierarchy meant all the difference. The ads should be on top.